# Struct loses track of variables when using pthread_create

Tags: c, multithreading, memory, struct, pthreads

I am trying to create a new thread that runs a function called csvSearch. The function requires 3 pieces of information, so I put those into a struct.

csvSearch takes a `(void *)` as its argument, and when casting that pointer back to a pointer to the struct, somehow I lose the data stored in `outpath` and `column`, two of the struct's fields.

This is the struct definition:

```
typedef struct {
    char path[256];
    char outpath[256];
    char column[32];
} Data;
```

When creating the thread I used the following code

```
Data *data = malloc(sizeof(Data *));

strcpy(data->path, path);
strcpy(data->outpath, outpath);
strcpy(data->column, column);

pthread_create(&threads[threadCount], NULL, csvSearch, data);
```

This is a summary of csvSearch, the function I'm trying to call

```
void *csvSearch(void * data){

    Data * input = (Data *) data;

    char * path = input->path;
    char * outpath = input->outpath;
    char * column = input->column;

//path is the correct string, but outpath and column are both empty strings
}
```

I've used gdb to test this extensively, and have been unable to find the issue. I know that up until `pthread_create`, data contains the proper information, and that I get the same memory address and size when it's cast back into a `Data *`, but `input->outpath` and `input->column` are both filled with null characters.

Is something in my syntax incorrect? Or can you not pass information to a function in a new thread this way?

Comment: Great presentation of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Data *data = malloc(sizeof(Data *));
```

is allocating memory for a `Data*` and not `Data`.You need

```
Data *data = malloc(sizeof(Data));
```

Comment: Or better yet, use `sizeof *data`.